# Python Celery - How to call celery tasks inside other task

Tags: python, django, celery, djcelery

I'm calling a task within a tasks in Django-Celery

Here are my tasks.

```
@shared_task
def post_notification(data,url):
    url = "http://posttestserver.com/data/?dir=praful" # when in production, remove this line.
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
    requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)


@shared_task
def shipment_server(data,notification_type):
    notification_obj = Notification.objects.get(name = notification_type)
    server_list = ServerNotificationMapping.objects.filter(notification_name=notification_obj)

    for server in server_list:
        task = post_notification.delay(data,server.server_id.url)
        print task.status # it prints 'Nonetype' has no attribute id
```

**How can I call a task within a task?**
I read somewhere it can be done using `group`, but I'm not able to form the correct syntax. How do I do it?

**I tried this**

```
for server in server_list:
    task = group(post_notification.s(data, server.server_id.url))().get()
    print task.status
```

Throws a warning saying

```
TxIsolationWarning: Polling results w│                                                                        
ith transaction isolation level repeatable-read within the same transacti│                                                                        
on may give outdated results. Be sure to commit the transaction for each │                                                                        
poll iteration.                                                          │                                                                        
  'Polling results with transaction isolation level '
```

Dont know what it is!!!

How do I solve my problem?

Comment: `result = task.delay`/`task.apply_async` gives an `AsyncResult` object.  This supports a polling `.status` attribute which each time its accessed will check what the state of the task is.  It makes no sense to call .state right after you have sent the task because chances are the worker did not start executing it yet.  In your later example you call `task = .....get().status` which will not work because you are calling status on the return value of the task, not the result (result.status vs result.get().status).

Comment: Finally you should not wait for the result of a subtask because that may lead to deadlocks, instead you should use a callback task: `(post_notification.s() | do_sometihing_after_posted.s()).delay()`.  See http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#avoid-launching-synchronous-subtasks and http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work:

```
celery.current_app.send_task('mymodel.tasks.mytask', args=[arg1, arg2, arg3])
```

Comment: What is my_model and current_app?

Comment: `current_app` is property of celery module. `mymodel.tasks` is a path to your `tasks.py`. Change it if necessary.

Comment: so, I should do something like this `task = celery.current_app.send_task('mymodel.tasks.mytask', args=[arg1, arg2, arg3]) `

Comment: Since the task to be called is in the same module, I'm doing like this `task = celery.current_app.send_task('post_notification', args=[data, url])
  print task.status`

Comment: `celery.current_app.send_task` will return `AsyncResult` instance. The task will be executed.

Comment: and check the path to tasks file

Comment: Note that you don't have to use `send_task`, you can use `task.delay` from a task without problems, your problem is polling the result object that is returned.

Comment: Worked fine here! Thanks...

I use `from celery._state import current_app` to version 4.2.x

Answer (score 4):

You are right, because each task in you `for` loop will be overwrite `task` variable.

You can try `celery.group` like

```
from celery import group
```

and

```
@shared_task
def shipment_server(data,notification_type):
    notification_obj = Notification.objects.get(name = notification_type)
    server_list = ServerNotificationMapping.objects.filter(notification_name=notification_obj)


    tasks = [post_notification.s(data, server.server_id.url) for server in server_list]
    results = group(tasks)()
    print results.get() # results.status() what ever you want
```

Comment: calling .get() inside a task is bad practice that can lead to dead locks. You need to be very careful about it.

Answer (score 1):

you can call task from a task using delay function

```
from app.tasks import celery_add_task
    celery_add_task.apply_async(args=[task_name])
```

... it will work